# Shutter snapshot tool to copy image to clipboard

Tags: screenshot, shutter, snapshot

I'm a new Ubuntu Desktop user and looking for snapshot tool to use as alternative to Greenshot in Windows.

I found Shutter is the one. Though I want to copy the image in `Shutter built-in editor` to clipboard so that I can paste it quickly to my post(s) on the web.

But selecting copy on the editor menu not get me there. So how can we have snapshot image to be copied to Ubuntu clipboard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the final answer for this

1. Make sure **Shutter main window shown** after taking the snapshot. You could config this in Shutter option/preference
2. Do the **annotation** on the image
3. **Save** it - you will be brought back to the `main window`
4. Hit **Ctrl-C/Copy**
5. Done - you got the snapshot in the clipboard

Comment: Not sure why you wouldn't simply use `gnome-screenshot -c` or `gnome-screenshot -ac`, ( the latter for an area).

Comment: I need annotion tools on the snapshot e.g. auto-numbering, highlighter, text editor, arrow, rectangle ect. Only available in Shutter.

Comment: perfect.  Shutter's docs are a bit dire.

Answer (score 12):

I am not familiar with Greenshot but there are some default key combinations under Xenial Xerus LTS which should help you out. Note in particular the 3 sets of key combinations that send *directly* to the clipboard:

[image]

Working well here and should work well for you as well :)

Comment: This is Ubuntu system screenshots utility not Shutter tool right - I'm looking for copying it from Shutter editor. Thanks for your tips any way.

Comment: @NamGVU OIC, I have had a closer look at shutter and certainly on my system a right click on the screenshot itself and select 'Copy' works. But not on your system?

Comment: Yeah, must do that outside the editor. Thanks.

Comment: @NamGVU I was going to add this to my answer but you have answered the question yourself?

Comment: Please note the time... I posted the same time you comment. Not taking yours as an answer. I'm not that style.

Comment: @NamGVU Hey I am just glad to see that you have at least partially solved your issue :)

Answer (score 4):

Found a workaround, though not directly from the editor, as steps below.

1. Open `Shutter Session` as the attached snapshot
2. `Pick up your snapshot` in the listing
3. `Right click - Copy` to copy it
4. Done - you got it on Ubuntu clipboard ready to paste.

[image]