# Cannot copy screenshot to clipboard in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: xorg, 17.10, clipboard, wayland, gnome-screenshot

The command `gnome-screenshot -c` is not copying the captured screenshot to my clipboard in Ubuntu 17.10.

How do I fix this?

[The answers in this question do not work for my Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343444/gnome-screenshot-copy-to-clipboard-shortcut)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. The problem was with the default **wayland** used in Ubuntu 17.10 which somehow affected other commands like `gksudo` and `gksu` too. When I logged into Ubuntu with **xorg**, everything worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If the command isn't working on v17.10 then you can try using shutter.

The steps to install shutter on your system are given below:

- Add the official repository - `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:shutter/ppa`
- Refresh system cache using the command - `sudo apt-get update`
- Begin the installation using - `sudo apt-get install shutter`

Once you have shutter installed on your system, you can refer to this link for more information - [using shutter to copy image to clipboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799588/shutter-snapshot-tool-to-copy-image-to-clipboard)

Apart from shutter, Ubuntu allows you to use default shortcuts too that help you in taking screenshots. The above link lists down those shortcuts as well.

Regards.

Comment: I do appreciate the alternative suggestion, but what I really want is a solution to fix the gnome-screenshot bug as I prefer it for its simplicity

Comment: Will surely look and help you in finding a solution for this issue brother. Let's see what other experts have a say on this.