# How do I take screenshot of restricted area with delay while sending the screenshot to clipboard at the same time?

Tags: screenshot, gnome-screenshot

How do I take a screenshot of restricted area with delay while sending the screenshot to clipboard?
I would like to get the screenshot stored on the clipboard to be able to paste it afterwards.

`gnome-screenshot -a -c` works but `gnome-screenshot -a -c --delay=2` does not work. It outputs the following:
`Conflicting options: --area and --delay should not be used at the same time.`

In case it is not possible to do this with gnome-screenshot, what other alternatives are there out there?

Thanks

Comment: `Shutter` provider the facility of a delay when taking a screen shot - including submenus. You can download it from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shutter snapshot tool to copy image to clipboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799588/shutter-snapshot-tool-to-copy-image-to-clipboard)

Comment: `Flameshot` will do the job. There are three different versions in the Software store... deb, flatpak, and snap.

Comment: I like shutter but, how can I make a keyboard shortcut to crop a restricted area with shutter?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "restricted area". If you mean redacting content from the shot captured by `Shutter` there is a option in the edit section of Shutter to do that (but not in `Screenshot Tool` that I recall.

Answer (score 0):

First take a delayed full screen shot, then crop the image.  I use GIMP to crop.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a delayed screenshot in `gnome-screenshot` is only possible for a full screen capture.

IF there is a need to automate the process, the command line screengrabber `scrot` can do this. It only outputs to a file, but in good linux tradition, you can subsequently use another tool, `xclip`, to place it on the clipboard.

```
scrot -s -d 4 -o image.png
xclip -sel c -t image/png -i image.png
```

This will allow you to make a selection (`s`) and after a delay of 4 seconds (`-d 4`) write out to `image.png`, overwriting `-o` the file if already present. The second command will link the file to the clipboard (`-sel c`) as a MIME type `image/png`.

This could be wrapped in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
TEMP=mktemp
scrot -s -d $1 -o $TEMP
xclip -sel c -t image/png -i $TEMP
```

`mktemp` creates a file with a random name in the `/tmp` folder. That folder is automatically cleaned on the next reboot. `$1` is the first argument to provide to the script. So if you call the script for example `ss`, then the command `ss 4` would introduce a delay of 4 seconds.